# wine on elementary os [looking for confirmation]

Tags: wine

i would like to know which wine packages can be installed in elementary os with official (default) sources.list

so i ll be grateful if someone can show me what show `apt install wine (click two times on <tab> button )`

for example for me it shows:

[image]

and test if it can install wine1.6-i386 == check if there are no errors

```
sudo apt install wine1.6-i386
```

Comment: `wine1.6-i386` Is not an available package, do you mean `wine1.6-amd64` or `wine1.4-i386`?

Comment: @Fultie for me `sudo apt list --installed`    return   `wine1.6-i386/xenial-updates,now 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2 i386 [installed]`

Comment: Why not try with `sudo apt install wine-stable`?

Answer (score 1):

> show me apt install wine

[image: apt install wine + tab]

`sudo apt install wine1.6-i386`

Gave me an error,

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Get:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe [652 B]
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe                           
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 652 B in 1s (341 B/s)                                                           
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch https://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/corefonts/andale32.exe  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
```

Which I solved by using Workaround 1 on [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1607535) Launchpad bug report.

[image: succesful installation of wine1.6-i386]